# Batch script: IF compaison is not working as expected

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('gpresult /r ^| FIND "string"') DO SET Result=%%A  
if '%Result%'=='this is where the word string shows up'  
echo Success > %homepath%\Desktop\Success.txt
```

Does not actually write the file to the desktop even though the strings match.

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

at the top of your batch file, and then instead of

```
'%Result%'=='this is where the word string shows up'
```

you need

```
'!Result!'=='this is where the word string shows up'
```

- notice the ! instead of %. Otherwise, %Result% is expanded when the batch file is first parsed, at which point the Result variable does not contain anything. These changes mean that it delays parsing it until its  within the for loop, by which point it will have been populated appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Try using setlocal enabledelayedexpansion in your code. Then access your variables using "!variable!" instead of "%variable%".
Also make sure if %%A is fetching the required token or not.

Answer (score 0):

The `echo` should be on the same line as the `if`:

```
if '%Result%'=='this is where the word string shows up' echo Success > %homepath%\Desktop\Success.txt
```

or put parentheses around it:

```
if '%Result%'=='this is where the word string shows up' (
    echo Success > %homepath%\Desktop\Success.txt
)
```